# How do I get only the final result of any Javascript in Python Requests module?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using both Requests and BeautifulSoup, and on most websites, the response I get from the following code just contains a bunch of Javascript (I don't know Javascript) which I think is the instructions for what content to display on the page, but I don't actually get the final result.

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

I want it to return something similar to what it looks like if I go to the inspect element tab, but instead it's looking more like I just right clicked and said view page source.

Is there a way to tell BeautifulSoup or Requests that I just want the final result and not all the Javascript?

Comment: Yes, `requests` gives you EXACTLY what "View Source" does.  If you need to execute Javascript, then you have to use a real browser.  That means either Selenium or `requests-html`, both of which invoke Chrome.  In that case, you don't need to use BeautifulSoup -- Selenium has APIs to troll through the DOM.